# How to make jQuery.ajax call in external reusable javascript file in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

## Issue

I have a function in file `add-cp-modal.js` called `dbInsertCostPlace(nameText)` that calls another function in file `wpdb-helper.js` called `dbInsertCostPlace(onSuccess, onError)` that makes a `jQuery.ajax` call. However, the ajax call does not work when it's inside the seperate file `wpdb-helper.js`. The ajax call does only work when it is in the same file as the function calling it.

## Files

### `add-cp-modal.js`, calling ajax function in `wpdb-helper.js`:

```
<div id="add-costplace-modal" class="add-costplace-modal-background">

    <div class="add-costplace-modal">

      <div class="add-costplace-modal-headerr">
        <div class="add-costplace-modal-headerr-left-box">
          Skapa kostnadsstÃƒÂ¤lle
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="add-costplace-modal-body">

        <div class="add-costplace-modal-name-form">

          <div class="add-costplace-modal-name-form-label">
            Namn:
          </div>
          <input id="add-costplace-modal-name-textfield" type="text" class="add-costplace-modal-name-textfield">

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="add-costplace-modal-footer">
        <button id="add-costplace-modal-save-button">Spara</button>
        <button id="add-costplace-modal-cancel-button">Avbryt</button>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <script>

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      addCpModal.init();
    }, false);

    var addCpModal = {

      init: function() {
        this.addButtonListeners();
      },

      addButtonListeners: function() {
        document.getElementById("add-costplace-modal-save-button").addEventListener("click", this.savePressed);
        document.getElementById("add-costplace-modal-cancel-button").addEventListener("click", this.cancelPressed);
      },

      savePressed: function() {
        var nameText = addCpModal.getNameText();
        addCpModal.dbInsertCostPlace(nameText);
        addCpModal.hide();
      },

      dbInsertCostPlace: function(nameText) {
        wpdbhelper.dbInsertCostPlace(addCpModal.onCostPlacePostSuccess, addCpModal.onCostPlacePostError);
      },

      onCostPlacePostSuccess: function(result) {
        alert("onCostPlacePostSuccess");
        addCpModal.loadCostPlaces();
      },

      loadCostPlaces: function(){
        wpdbhelper.loadCostPlaces(addCpModal.onCostPlacesGetSuccess, addCpModal.onCostPlacesGetError);
      },

      onCostPlacesGetSuccess: function(result) {
        alert("onCostPlacesGetSuccess");
        cpTable.setData(result);
      },

      onCostPlacesGetError: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error occurred getting cost places.");
      },

      onCostPlacePostError: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error occurred posting cost place.");
      },

      getNameText: function() {
        var nameTextfield = document.getElementById("add-costplace-modal-name-textfield");
        return nameTextfield.value;
      },

      hide: function() {
        var modal = document.getElementById("add-costplace-modal");
        modal.style["visibility"] = "hidden";
      },

      cancelPressed: function() {
        addCpModal.hide();
      },

      show: function() {
        var modal = document.getElementById("add-costplace-modal");
        modal.style["visibility"] = "visible";
      }

    };

</script>
```

### `wpdb-helper.js` containing the ajax call function:

```
<script>

  var wpdbhelper = {

    dbInsertCostPlace: function(onSuccess, onError) {
      console.log("wpdb-helper: ajaxurl: " + ajaxurl);
      jQuery.ajax({
        url : ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          'action': 'insert_costplace',
          'data': {
            'name': nameText,
            'age': 17
            }
        },
        success: function(result) {
          console.log("SUCCESS");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log("ERROR");
        }
      });
      console.log("wpdb-helper: After ajax call.\n");
    },

    loadCostPlaces: function (onSuccess, onError){
        console.log("loadCostPlaces called inside wpdbhelper");
        jQuery.ajax({
          url : ajaxurl,
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
            action: 'get_costplaces'
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(result) {
            console.log("SUCCESS");
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("ERROR");
          }
        });
      }

  };

</script>
```

Comment: It depends how do you declare your third party libs...it seems that `jQuery` is not defined globally. Maybe you can try to pass `jQuery` instance - `dbInsertCostPlace: function(jQuery, onSuccess, onError)` and call it with `dbInsertCostPlace($, onSuccess, onError)`

Comment: @ymz First I printed jQuery in wpdb-helper and it was not defined. I also tried passing the jQuery object like you suggested, but still nothing happend when it runs the ajax call.

Comment: I haven't read the entire thing but it looks like you have a `*.js` file that contains HTML...? That won't work. Or did you mean to write `add-cp-modal.php`?

Comment: @ChrisG no, it is a .js file. I am pretty new to javascript. The javascript is in <script> tags though. Should I make it to a .html file instead if I mix html with javascript?

Comment: Unless you're using a special framework, you cannot put any HTML into a `*.js` file, not even `<script>` tags. A JS file contains JS, and JS only. If you need to add both HTML and JS to a wordpress page, you need to add the HTML using the templating system and add the script separately. The above script should definitely result in a parse error visible in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this short (but great) [article](https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/):

Include your jQuery definition in the footer (instead of header) using `wp_enqueue_script("jquery");`

you can also add an anonymous scope (again, in the footer) to use `$` instead of `jQuery` using:

```
(function($) {

    // $ Works! You can test it with next line if you like
    // console.log($);

})( jQuery );
```

That should make `jQuery` visible from all your files in project

Comment: I tried that as well. Didn't work. There hasn't been any problem with jQuery being undefined. But for some reason calling jQuery.ajax(), just doesn't do anything. No errors, no log, nothing.

Comment: In that case, inspect your network traffic (using your browser developer tools - for instance: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network) and verify that your ajax call is recorded there and has correct values (perhaps `ajaxurl` is not defined in your external file properly)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and it feels very silly now. The variable "nameText" was undefined. I forgot to pass it into the wpdp-helper method as an argument. Once I passed in a nameText value the ajax call worked.